# F# List of Union Types

Tags: list, f#, discriminated-union

I want a list of Reports. Report can be either Detail or Section types.

```
module Data

type Section = { Header: string;
                 Lines:  string list;
                 Total:  string }

type Detail = { State:     string;
                Divisions: string list;
                Sections:  Section list }

type Summary = { State:    string;
                 Office:   string;
                 Sections: Section list }

type Report = Detail | Summary
```

Then in my code, I'd like to do the following:

```
let mutable (reports:Report list) = []

...

reports <- detail::reports
// or
reports <- summary::reports
```

The compiler complains in the first case: "The expression was expected to have type Report but here has type Detail", and appropriately similarly in the second case.

Am I out of my mind for wanting to do such a thing? Should I be thinking about the problem differently? Because Report is either Detail or Summary, shouldn't a list of Report accept either a Detail or a Summary? What is a Report list if not a list of Detail or Summary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've just got your syntax a bit wrong:

```
type Report = Detail of Detail | Summary of Summary

reports <- (Detail detail)::reports
// or
reports <- (Summary summary)::reports
```

In your code you've basically just defined the `Report` type to be an enum with the two possible values `Details` or `Summary` (these are like labels, not the types of different subtypes in this context).  Discriminated unions in F# are explicitly tagged, so you've also got to use one of the union constructors to create an instance to put into the list.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your `Report` type to:

```
type Report = Detail of Detail | Summary of Summary
```

since your current definition just names the two cases of your Report type, and these names are not related to the existing `Detail` and `Summary` types.

You can then filter the `Detail` and `Summary` elements using `List.choose` e.g.

```
let details = reports |> List.choose (function Detail(d) -> Some(d) | _ -> None)
```