# Operating on an F# List of Union Types

Tags: list, f#, discriminated-union

This is a continuation of my question at [F# List of Union Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770911/f-list-of-union-types). Thanks to the helpful feedback, I was able to create a list of `Report`s, with `Report` being either `Detail` or `Summary`. Here's the data definition once more:

```
module Data

type Section = { Header: string;
                 Lines:  string list;
                 Total:  string }

type Detail = { State:     string;
                Divisions: string list;
                Sections:  Section list }

type Summary = { State:    string;
                 Office:   string;
                 Sections: Section list }

type Report = Detail of Detail | Summary of Summary
```

Now that I've got the list of `Report`s in a variable called `reports`, I want to iterate over those `Report` objects and perform operations based on each one. The operations are the same except for the cases of dealing with either `Detail.Divisions` or `Summary.Office`. Obviously, I have to handle those differently. But I don't want to duplicate all the code for handling the similar `State` and `Sections` of each.

My first (working) idea is something like the following:

```
for report in reports do
    let mutable isDetail  = false
    let mutable isSummary = false

    match report with
    | Detail  _ -> isDetail  <- true
    | Summary _ -> isSummary <- true

    ...
```

This will give me a way to know when to handle `Detail.Divisions` rather than `Summary.Office`. But it doesn't give me an object to work with. I'm still stuck with `report`, not knowing which it is, `Detail` or `Summary`, and also unable to access the attributes. I'd like to convert `report` to the appropriate `Detail` or `Summary` and then use the same code to process either case, with the exception of `Detail.Divisions` and `Summary.Office`. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
for report in reports do
    match report with
    | Detail { State = s; Sections = l }
    | Summary { State = s; Sections = l } ->
        // common processing for state and sections (using bound identifiers s and l)

    match report with
    | Detail { Divisions = l } ->
        // unique processing for divisions
    | Summary { Office = o } ->
        // unique processing for office
```

Comment: This is the technique I actually ended up using. I think I like Thomas' approach the best, but I implemented before he responded. My task was essentially imperative (looping through a print file line by line and parsing), so I ended up with some pretty non-idiomatic F# code. But this technique served me well. Thank you!

Comment: Inspired by this answer, I added another version to my answer. The idea is to hide these three patterns (that may be used repeatedly in the program) in active patterns.

Answer (score 4):

The answer by @kvb is probably the approach I would use if I had the data structure you described. However, I think it would make sense to think whether the data types you have are the best possible representation.

The fact that both `Detail` and `Summary` share two of the properties (`State` and `Sections`) perhaps implies that there is some common part of a `Report` that is shared regardless of the kind of report (and the report can either add `Divisions` if it is detailed or just `Office` if if is summary).

Something like that would be better expressed using the following (`Section` stays the same, so I did not include it in the snippet):

```
type ReportInformation = 
  | Divisions of string list
  | Office of string

type Report = 
  { State       : string;
    Sections    : Section list 
    Information : ReportInformation }
```

If you use this style, you can just access `report.State` and `report.Sections` (to do the common part of the processing) and then you can match on `report.Information` to do the varying part of the processing.

**EDIT -** In answer to Jeff's comment - if the data structure is already fixed, but the view has changed, you can use F# *active patterns* to write "adaptor" that provides access to the old data structure using the view that I described above:

```
let (|Report|) = function
  | Detail dt -> dt.State, dt.Sections
  | Summary st -> st.State, st.Sections

let (|Divisions|Office|) = function
  | Detail dt -> Divisions dt.Divisions
  | Summary st -> Office st.Office
```

The first active pattern always succeeds and extracts the common part. The second allows you to distinguish between the two cases. Then you can write:

```
let processReport report =
  let (Report(state, sections)) = report
  // Common processing
  match report wiht
  | Divisions divs -> // Divisions-specific code
  | Office ofc -> // Offices-specific code
```

This is actually an excellent example of how F# active patterns provide an abstraction that allows you to hide implementation details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Tomas. I had a working application with my data structure, and then the user flipped a new/different requirement out on me (Hey, let's use the summary for these specific offices rather than the detail). I probably should have started from scratch with a data definition like you describe. Alas, hindsight is 20/20, and I was loathe to scrap a program that, for the original specs, worked perfectly!

Comment: Aah, that's an interesting thing to know! I added an example with active patterns that might give you a nice way to look at the existing data types through a different (perhaps more appropriate) way.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you for this. I've never quite grasped Active Patterns. Maybe now is the time to put forth the extra effort required to do so!

Answer (score 3):

kvb's answer is good, and probably what I would use. But the way you've expressed your problem sounds like you want classic inheritance.

```
type ReportPart(state, sections) =
  member val State = state
  member val Sections = sections

type Detail(state, sections, divisions) =
  inherit ReportPart(state, sections) 
  member val Divisions = divisions

type Summary(state, sections, office) =
  inherit ReportPart(state, sections) 
  member val Office = office
```

Then you can do precisely what you expect:

```
for report in reports do
  match report with
  | :? Detail as detail ->   //use detail.Divisions
  | :? Summary as summary -> //use summary.Office
  //use common properties
```

Comment: I like this answer. But I shy away from inheritance for some reason. I'll keep it in mind for future projects, though. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can pattern match on the `Detail` or `Summary` record in each of the union cases when you match and handle the `Divisions` or `Office` value with a separate function e.g.

```
let blah =
    for report in reports do
        let out = match report with
        | Detail({ State = state; Divisions = divisions; Sections = sections } as d) -> 
            Detail({ d with Divisions = (handleDivisions divisions) })
        | Summary({ State = state; Office = office; Sections = sections } as s) -> 
            Summary( { s with Office = handleOffice office })

    //process out
```

Answer (score 2):

You can refactor the code to have a utility function for each common field and use nested pattern matching:

```
let handleReports reports =
   reports |> List.iter (function 
                  | Detail {State = s; Sections = ss; Divisions = ds} ->
                     handleState s
                     handleSections ss
                     handleDivisions ds
                  | Summary {State = s; Sections = ss; Office = o} ->
                     handleState s
                     handleSections ss
                     handleOffice o)
```

You can also filter `Detail` and `Summary` to process them separately in different functions:

```
let getDetails reports =
    List.choose (function Detail d -> Some d | _ -> None) reports 

let getSummaries reports =
    List.choose (function Summary s -> Some s | _ -> None) reports
```